# C# Word document 'printto' - 'there is a printer error' for every document printed

Tags: c#, printing, ms-word

When trying to use the 'ProcessStartInfo' and 'printto' verb to print word documents, a message box from MS Word is shown to the user for every document printed stating 'There is a printer error'.
The document still prints successfully however this is a big impact to processing time for users of this app.

Error message:[Word error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJEBf.png)

Here is my current code to print the documents:

```
private static void PrintDocument(string document)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(printerName))
    {
        ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(document);
        info.Verb = "PrintTo";
        info.Arguments = printerName;
        info.CreateNoWindow = true;
        info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

        Process.Start(info);
    }
    else
    {
        PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();
        if (pd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            printerName = pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName;
            PrintDocument(document);
        }
    }
}
```

Is anybody able to advise?

Comment: Can you open the document manually using Word and hit print, and that works?

Comment: Yeah, do you get any error messages in Word when you do this manually?

Answer (score 0):

I see that your print document function is `static`.
I think the issue may be that you are starting the process, leaving it hanging then calling it again.
Try:

```
Process.Start(info);
Process.WaitForExit();
var exitCode = Process.ExitCode; //useful to handle errors
```

Answer (score 0):

When you start a new process by passing a path to the document the default editor will be launched for that. So, you can't be sure Word will be always handling such tasks. So, I'd suggest automating Word instead. The [Document.PrintOut](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.printout) method prints all or part of the specified document. You can configure the default printer in C# before calling it.